# Why if I print an address does it solve my code problem?

Tags: c

My code has a problem with a variable taking value from another one but when I print its address, it doesn't do it anymore. "Tiempo" keep taking the value from "Ahorrado" or "mes[2]".

When I printf the "tiempo" address, it stops doing it.

```
int main(void)    
{
    int mes[2];
    int ahorrado=0;
    int tiempo=0;

    mes[0]=100;
    tiempo++;

    //printf("",&tiempo);

    printf("%d%c ",tiempo,167);
    printf("mes: %d\n",mes[0]);

    mes[1]=100;
    tiempo++;

    printf("%d%c ",tiempo,167);
    printf("mes: %d\n",mes[1]);

    mes[2]=mes[0]+mes[1];
    tiempo++;
    ahorrado=mes[2];

    printf("%d%c ",tiempo,167);
    printf("mes: %d\nAhorrado: %d\n",mes[2],ahorrado);

    mes[1]=mes[2];
    mes[2]=mes[0]+mes[1];
    tiempo++;
    ahorrado+=mes[2];

    printf("%d%c",tiempo,167);
    printf("mes: %d + %d\nAhorrado: %d\n",mes[0],mes[1],ahorrado);

    mes[0]=mes[1];
    mes[1]=mes[2];

    while(ahorrado<=20000)
    {
        tiempo++;
        printf("%d%c",tiempo,167);
        printf("mes: %d + %d\nAhorrado: %d\n",mes[0],mes[1],ahorrado);
        mes[2]=mes[0]+mes[1];
        ahorrado+=mes[2];
        mes[0]=mes[1];
        mes[1]=mes[2];
    }

    printf("%d",ahorrado);
    return 0;    
}
```

i expect the "mes" showing 1 plus 1 not in high jump numbers.

Comment: You declared `mes` to be an array of only 2 integers. So `mes[2] = mes[0]+mes[1]` is invalid and will yield undefined behavior. Valid array access are `mes[0]` and `mes[1]`.

Comment: You invoke undefined behaviour.  Undefined behaviour is funny (funny peculiar, not funny ha-ha) stuff.  One of the acceptable responses is working as expected (even if the expectations are misguided), and another is behaving unexpectedly — and the unexpected behaviour can take many forms, from crashing to producing wrong results to overwriting unexpected variables, to … . Don't risk it.  Don't use undefined behaviour.  One major problem is that it can be hard to spot when you've incurred it, but writing outside of the bounds of an array is one well-known and obvious way to do it.

Comment: i messed up so badly hahaha, i knew about that undefined behaviour writing outside the defined limit of the array but i could not see the problem, thank you all.